# Connecting to multiple CosmosDB documents

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to have multiple documents in Cosmos, one will hold some data from a submit form once it is submitted.  I am trying to have a few other documents to hold the data for a drop down select list.  How am I able to connect to multiple config.containerId to read some data and then write some data?  I am currently only able to read/write to one.

Thanks for any help!

```
const config = {};

config.host = process.env.HOST || "https://localhost:8081";
config.authKey =
  process.env.AUTH_KEY || "key";
config.databaseId = "ToDoList";
config.containerId = "Items";
config.containerId2 = "List";

if (config.host.includes("https://localhost:")) {
  console.log("Local environment detected");
  console.log("WARNING: Disabled checking of self-signed certs. Do not have this code in production.");
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
  console.log(`Go to http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || '3000'} to try the sample.`);
}

module.exports = config;
```

```
const CosmosClient = require('@azure/cosmos').CosmosClient
 const config = require('./config')
 const TaskList = require('./routes/tasklist')
 const TaskDao = require('./models/taskDao')



 const express = require('express')
 const path = require('path')
 const logger = require('morgan')
 const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

 const app = express()

 // view engine setup
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
 app.set('view engine', 'jade')

 // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
 //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
 app.use(logger('dev'))
 app.use(bodyParser.json())
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 app.use(cookieParser())
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

 //Todo App:
 const cosmosClient = new CosmosClient({
   endpoint: config.host,
   key: config.authKey
 })
 const taskDao = new TaskDao(cosmosClient, config.databaseId, config.containerId)
 //const taskDao = new TaskDao(cosmosClient, config.databaseId, config.containerId2)
 const taskList = new TaskList(taskDao)


 taskDao
   .init(err => {
     console.error(err)
   })
   .catch(err => {
     console.error(err)
     console.error(
       'Shutting down because there was an error settinig up the database.'
     )
     process.exit(1)
   })



 app.get('/', (req, res, next) => taskList.showTasks(req, res).catch(next))

 app.post('/addtask', (req, res, next) => taskList.addTask(req, res).catch(next))
 app.post('/completetask', (req, res, next) =>
   taskList.completeTask(req, res).catch(next)
 )
 app.set('view engine', 'jade')


 // catch 404 and forward to error handler
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   const err = new Error('Not Found')
   err.status = 404
   next(err)
 })

 // error handler
 app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   // set locals, only providing error in development
   res.locals.message = err.message
   res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {}

   // render the error page
   res.status(err.status || 500)
   res.render('error')
 })



 module.exports = app
```

```
form(action="/completetask", method="post")
       label Closure Plan:
       <select name="ClosurePlan" id="ClosurePlanList" type="form" >
       if (typeof tasks === "undefined")
           tr
             td
         else
           each task in tasks
             tr
                <option value="Planned Closure">#{task.name}</option>
```

Rest of the code is from here:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-application.md

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you have 2 containers, and you want to read/write DBs of these two containers in your node.js project?

Comment: Yes, I want it to read to items from one container. Then write items to the second container once submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to instantiate another `TaskDao` to connect to your second container. Pls follow the steps below :

1. Make sure that you have followed [the doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-application.md) and you can run the website on your local successfully as all my code modification is based on this demo.
2. In my case, I have a DB named "ToDoList" which has two collections "Items" and "Items2".

   Go to `config.js` and add two configs for `Items2`:

   ```
   config.databaseId2 = "ToDoList";
   config.containerId2 = "Items2";
   ```

   [image]

Go to `app.js` , instantiate `TaskDao2` :

```
 const taskDao2 = new TaskDao(cosmosClient, config.databaseId2, config.containerId2)
 taskDao
   .init(err => {
     console.error(err)
   })
   .catch(err => {
     console.error(err)
     console.error(
       'Shutting down because there was an error settinig up the database.'
     )
     process.exit(1)
   })
 taskDao2
 .init(err => {
   console.error(err)
 })
 .catch(err => {
   console.error(err)
   console.error(
     'Shutting down because there was an error settinig up the database.'
   )
   process.exit(1)
 })

 const taskList = new TaskList(taskDao,taskDao2)
```

[image]

Finally, go to `routes/tasklist.js`, modify `constructor` method as below :

```
   constructor(taskDao,taskDao2) {
     this.taskDao = taskDao;
     this.taskDao2 = taskDao2;
   }
```

[image]

With this step is done, your app could connect to your another collection successfully. I write the same data to items2 collection when we adding tasks, go to `addTask` method and add the code below :

```
await this.taskDao2.addItem(item);
```

[image]

Ok, lets start the web app and add a task :
[image]

Have a check the data in cosmos db :
[image]
[image]

As you can see, you can write data to another collection now. Hope it helps .

Comment: Can we get query results from multiple tables? And create a querySpec1 and querySpec2?        
Ex: 

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => taskList.List1(req, res).catch(next))
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => taskList.List2(req, res).catch(next))